# SQL replace string by variable character position

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, oracle11g

I'm using `Oracle 11.g`.  I have to `replace` a string within an eMail clob before I send it.  The large string looks like:

```
<p>
Text right before the HP image.</p>
<p>
<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,//(a variable amount of encoded data)//"></p>
<p>
Text right after the image.</p>
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
```

The text before as well as the text after the `IMG` tag will be of variable length.  I'd like to replace the large amount of text within the `IMG` tag:

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,//(a variable amount of encoded data)//">
```

With the following text consistently:

```
<img src="cid:image.jpg" alt="This is a banner"/>
```

I use `INSTR` to find the start and end of the `IMG` tag and store them in local variables.  I can't figure out how to replace by those variable positions.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to accomplish this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mytext, '<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[^"]*">', '<img src="cid:image.jpg" alt="This is a banner"/>', 'i') AS mynewtext
  FROM mytable
```

It might be better to do the search-and-replace in your sending code rather than in the query itself.

Comment: You're welcome. Regular expressions are great for this sort of thing and Oracle has a decent regex engine.